# Augmenting a matrix in Python using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to augment a matrix to solve an equation, yet have been unable to. And yes, I saw the "Augment a matrix in NumPy" question; it is not what I need.

So my problem: create an augmented matrix [ A **b1** **b2** ]

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([[1,2],[5,12]])
b1 = numpy.array([-1,3]).T
b2 = numpy.array([1,-5]).T
```

I've tried the numpy.concatenate function, returns

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Is there a way to augment the matrix, such that I have one array of

> [ 1 2 -1  1
>
> 5 12 3 -5 ]

If anyone knows, please inform me! Note that I was doing this in the IPython notebook

(btw, I know that I can't row reduce it with Numpy, it's a university problem, and just was doing the rest in IPython)

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stack 1D arrays as if they were column vectors using the [`np.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) function. This should do what you are after:

```
>>> np.column_stack((a, b1, b2))
array([[ 1,  2, -1,  1],
       [ 5, 12,  3, -5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I put your code into Ipython, and ask for the array shapes:

```
In [1]: a = numpy.array([[1,2],[5,12]])

In [2]: b1 = numpy.array([-1,3]).T

In [3]: b2 = numpy.array([1,-5]).T

In [4]: a.shape
Out[4]: (2, 2)

In [5]: b1.shape
Out[5]: (2,)

In [6]: b2.shape
Out[6]: (2,)
```

Notice `a` has 2 dimensions, the others `1`.  The `.T` does nothing on the 1d arrays.

Try making `b1` a 2d.  Also make sure you are concatenating on the right axis.

```
In [7]: b1 = numpy.array([[-1,3]]).T

In [9]: b1.shape
Out[9]: (2, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.concatenate()` requires that all arrays have the same number of dimensions, so you have to augment the 1d vectors to 2d using `None` or `numpy.newaxis` like so:

```
>>> numpy.concatenate((a, b1[:,None], b2[:,None]), axis=1)
array([[ 1,  2, -1,  1],
       [ 5, 12,  3, -5]])
```

There are also the shorthands `r_` and `c_` for row/column concatenation, which mimic Matlab's notation:

```
>>> from numpy import c_
>>> c_[a, b1, b2]
array([[ 1,  2, -1,  1],
       [ 5, 12,  3, -5]])
```

Look up the source code to understand how they work ;-)